# Manually trigger on-screen keyboard in Windows Universal App on Windows 10 IoT Core?

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, iot, windows-10-iot-core

For some reason the on-screen keyboard in Windows 10 IoT Core on raspberry pi 2 model b does not always come to front. (actually 99% it does not work).

is is possible to manually make a call in codebehind (for example when the OnFocus event happens) to show the osk?

Comment: What's your windows 10 iot core version? Can you provide a code sample to reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

The osk is actually a separate program, you could call it using the External Process Launcher API.
https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/iot/samples/externalprocesslauncher

From what I understand it is only available on Windows SDK: Version 15063 and up however.

I don't have the SDK installed at work so this code may be wrong, but it would look a bit like this:

```
var result = await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync("C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe", string.Empty);
```

Edit: 
 
I'm thinking this may block the UI Thread though, which would be undesirable. Maybe if you run the task in the background though... Perhaps through the CoreDispatcher. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcher#Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcher_RunAsync_Windows_UI_Core_CoreDispatcherPriority_Windows_UI_Core_DispatchedHandler_

```
var ignored = dispatcher.RunAsync(CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
    {
        await ProcessLauncher.RunToCompletionAsync("C:\\Windows\\System32\\osk.exe", string.Empty);
    });
```

Comment: I'm seeing this in the release notes for 14971...
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1d5244ac-bf5c-486c-a203-b0406bc858f6/new-flight-14971-released-for-insiders?forum=WindowsIoT

"An On Screen Keyboard (OSK) was added as an optional package and was added to the default FFUs. The OSK is disabled by default and must be enabled via the new option in Windows Devices Portal (Web Management)."

Comment: yes I've enabled it in the device portal, but if I browse the device via windows explorer (remote) I don't see osk.exe in the system32 folder. does it have a different name? The problem is the default provided osk does not always popup on textbox focus... trying to solve this issue. (or I could wait for a windows update...)